# jQuery toggleClass if another element is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a project with jQuery 1.11.2.1

where this jquery statement was working with no problems:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {   
  $(".clickme").click(function(){
       $("#menu").toggleClass("fixed", $( $("#panel").is(":visible") ) );
       $("#panel").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

after I moved to jQuery 1.11.3.2
browser freezes whenever I click the ".clickme" button and ask me to block a script (jquery) that was hanging too long.

I had to remove the is visible condition to avoid browser hanging:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    $(".clickme").click(function(){
        $("#menu").toggleClass("fixed");
        $("#panel").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

the problem is I need to check the visibility of the #panel element.

element #panel default state is display:none

the issue is present in all browsers I can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is almost correct, except that you're putting a boolean (from `.is()`) in to a jQuery object. The boolean needs to be given directly as a parameter to the `toggleClass` method. Try this:

```
$(".clickme").click(function(){
   $("#menu").toggleClass("fixed", $("#panel").is(":visible"));
   $("#panel").slideToggle();
});
```

[More info on toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state)

Comment: Hi Rory, your suggestion is working fine. Can I ask you why it was working before upgrade? (it's a wordpress site). Look here, the previous version: http://greenparkmadama.it/  the script is http://greenparkmadama.it/wp-content/themes/greenparkmadama/js/greenparkmadama.js?ver=0.7  from line 21

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. It really shouldn't have been. It was possibly a fixed bug. I haven't checked the release notes to see what changed between versions.

Comment: that's weird! furthermore, the condition was wrong: I needed to check if it was hidden, not if it was visibile! I made this script about 2 years ago, and it worked till now. mesmerizing! ;)  Many thanks anyway